# Syncing RewriteBase and HTML base tag

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For a small PHP web application I want to start right away with beautiful links. Therefore I put an .htaccess with *mod_rewrite* in the base directory of my app to redirect up to three levels of "directories" to an index.php-file, giving the directories as a parameter.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /appdirectory

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(/([^/]*)(/([^/]*))?)?$ ./index.php?id1=$1&id2=$3&id3=$5
```

This works perfectly, the only pitfall I noticed is that ressources reffered to in the PHP/HTML files by relative paths are not found anymore. This was no big surprise, since the browser is parsing the HTML and the browser only knows the beautified URL the user submitted to the server. I was able to solve this problem using the HTML base tag. I think of relative links as a quite elegant solution and definitely want to stick with them.

To make the app installable in a subdirectory of a webserver, I also had to add a *RewriteBase* to my .htaccess file. Obviously, the RewriteBase and the HTML base are allways the same for my app.

The problem in usability I see is, that the user who wants to install the application needs to set both the RewriteBase and the HTML base to the subdirectory on his or her server.

Is there a way to somehow sync both properties? Do you know any other solution which is more user-friendly? Is there a way to solve this problem by using a PHP variable containing the install subdirectory or even let it be autodetected somehow for both mod_rewrite and HTML?

Comment: Not really. It's only two things. Once it's set it's set. It's not like you have to keep changing this. It's a configuration that you do once. So it's really not that **un-user** friendly. We seem to want everything automated somehow. LOL it's just 2 lines.

Comment: I agree, I also consider this very basic stuff And it proably is for most other people who would ever want to use an app like this. But there are people out there who have never seen source coude before and get easily frustrated even by this stuff.

Comment: But that's why you learn it. Everything has a learning curve. When I first started with Apache many years ago, my mod_rewrite skills were nil. Even my PHP was basic. It just comes with learning. We all have to start somewhere. I got frustrated with basic stuff back then. Now most of this is 2nd nature. It comes with time.

Comment: Yes, I get your point. But I don't want the users of my apps to learn PHP and mod_rewrite in order to install and use it.

Comment: Well I haven't seen a framework or CMS that I didn't have to configure yet, so if they are getting into that. There is some work involved, period. Even with Wordpress. There are config files to modify and .htaccess rules that might change depending on if it's in a directory or not. That comes with the territory. Don't hold their hand or they won't understand it, if when they need to change something to work for them.